# Publish profile to rename Appsetting Is not working in Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have  Appsettings.release.json file and during Publish I want this file to be renamed as Appsettings.json

I have used below publish commands for the same. This is working Fine in  MVC APPLICATION, but not working in my Console Application. Code is published in Console application without any issue, but File renaming is not working.

for debugging added Text Message as **Inside AfterPublish** and it was printed in MVC application but not in Console Application.

Kindly let me know is it possible to rename Appsetting.release.json to appsetting.json in Console Application or not ?

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings*json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />  
    <FileToRename Include="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.Release.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="RenameAppSettingsProd" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Message Text="Inside AfterPublish" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FileToRename)" DestinationFiles="$(PublishDir)appsettings.json" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

I tried to rename Appsetting.release.json to appsetting.json using Publish Profile. It was working for MVC Project but not in Console Application.

Comment: Your codes is working well on my side, did you remove the previous file and make sure you select release as the publish mode?

Comment: its working in Console application ?

Comment: Yes, .net7 console application.

Comment: this is my Property group COnfig, Do i need to add anything  ?  <PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
  <PublishDir>bin\Release\net8.0\publish\</PublishDir>
  <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
  <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: Yes, it looks same, I directly publish it by using VS's publish command.